# My sunflower is dying what do i do?

Tags: plant-health, container-gardening, sunflowers

I have a potted sunflower and it was overwatered. Is there any way to revive it? It hasn't been watered in a week and the soil still seems very wet. Any help is much appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: There has to be a reason that soil is not drying out.  Let's figure that out for sure.  Are there drainage holes?  Did you put rocks/gravel/packing peanuts at the bottom above the holes and below the potting soil?  Did you use potting soil or is this soil from the garden full of clay that holds water very well?  I would transplant this sunflower into sterilized potting soil in a pot equal to its root ball.  Leave 1" from surface of soil to rim of pot.  Feel the heft of the pot watered and you'll be able to tell when it is lighter and when to water again. Check out the roots take a picture...

Comment: If you can post a picture of the plant and its leaves, that would be great. What condition is the plant in, currently? Is it healthy, but overwatered, or is it dying and overwatered? Are the leaves wilting, spotted, shriveling, or fine? Is it growing at all?

Comment: Welcome Elisa! This is a great first question! We're different from some other sites, so I'd like to introduce you to our system through our [help]. [Ask] explains why we're asking for more details.  Choose "edit" below your text to add to the question. If you need help with our features or how to do anything, leave a comment and someone will help you! Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Elisa. Since this is a sunflower it is probably quite big. If the pot it is in has no drainage holes or they are blocked, look around for a pot the same size with drainage holes. Consider moving the plant from the current pot to the new one and standing the lot on a layer of newspaper. The paper should help to get water out of the root ball. As the newspaper gets wet move the plant to a fresh stack and get more water out. If the pot has holes just do the newspaper thing until you think the root ball is just moist again.

If this suggestion is not feasible then perhaps you need to give us more information to be able to picture your situation.

Comment: Colin I really like this newspaper gig to suck the excess water from the soil.  Wow. Cheaper than paper towels for sure.  Newspaper is incredibly useful in gardening for protection from the elements, to use it to suck up excess water is brilliant.  There is a reason the soil is holding so much water and that needs to be addressed.